# Error con miles y decimales al formatear el resultado

Tags: javascript

Tengo este JS que realiza correctamente la función pero el error viene cuando muestra los resultados, ejem, introduciendo **6.900 €** muestra **104.634.883,097928** cuando debería ser  **104.634,88 €**
Mis conocimientos sobre este lenguaje son mínimos, y no se me ocurre la manera de formatear correctamente los decimales.
Me podéis dar un punto de luz???, gracias por vuestra ayuda y paciencia.

```html
<script>
function calculo() {

  //var TextBox1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("factura").value.replace(/,/g, '')) || 0;

  var Box1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("factura").value) || 0;
  var Box2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cuarenta").value) || 0;
  var Box3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cero").value) || 0;
  var Box4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("sesenta").value) || 0;
  var Box5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("doce").value) || 0;
  var Box6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("horario").value) || 0;
  var Box7 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("mil").value) || 0;
  var Box8 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("novecientoscincuenta").value) || 0;

  var result = Box1 * Box2 / Box3 * Box4 * Box5 * Box6 / Box7 * Box8;

  result.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("total").value = result;

  format(document.getElementById("total"));
}

var formatNumber = {
 separador: ".", // separador para los miles
 sepDecimal: ',', // separador para los decimales
 formatear:function (num){
  num +='';
  var splitStr = num.split('.');
  var splitLeft = splitStr[0];
  var splitRight = splitStr.length > 1 ? this.sepDecimal + splitStr[1] : '';
  var regx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
  while (regx.test(splitLeft)) {
  splitLeft = splitLeft.replace(regx, '$1' + this.separador + '$2');
  }
  return  splitLeft  +splitRight + ' ' + this.simbol;
 },
 new:function(num, simbol){
  this.simbol = simbol ||'';
  return this.formatear(num);
 }
}
function format(input) {
  var num = input.value;  
  input.value = formatNumber.new(num, "€");
} 
</script>
<input type="hidden" id="cuarenta" value="40" onkeyup="calculo()" /><br />   
<input type="hidden" id="cero" value="0.108253" onkeyup="calculo()" /><br />
<input type="hidden" id="sesenta" value="60" onkeyup="calculo()" /><br />
<input type="hidden" id="doce" value="12" onkeyup="calculo()" /><br />
<input type="hidden" id="doce" value="12" onkeyup="calculo()" /><br />
<input type="hidden" id="mil" value="1000" onkeyup="calculo()" /><br />
<input type="hidden" id="novecientoscincuenta" value="950" onkeyup="calculo()" />

<input type="text" name="Factura" id="factura" value="" onkeyup="calculo()"><br /><br />
<select class="form-control" onchange="calculo();" id="horario" name="Horario">
    <option selected>Seleccionar horario de consumo</option>
 <option id="dia" name="Día" value="60" onkeyup="calculo();" required>Día</option>
 <option id="noche" name="Noche" value="20" onkeyup="calculo();" required>Noche</option>
 <option id="ambos" name="Ambos" value="45" onkeyup="calculo();" required>Ambos</option>
</select><br /><br />

<input type="text" name="Total" id="total" value="" onkeyup="format(this)" disabled>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script>
function calculo() {

  //var TextBox1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("factura").value.replace(/,/g, '')) || 0;

  var Box1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("factura").value) || 0;
  var Box2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cuarenta").value) || 0;
  var Box3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cero").value) || 0;
  var Box4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("sesenta").value) || 0;
  var Box5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("doce").value) || 0;
  var Box6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("horario").value) || 0;
  var Box7 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("mil").value) || 0;
  var Box8 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("novecientoscincuenta").value) || 0;

  var result = Box1 * Box2 / Box3 * Box4 * Box5 * Box6 / Box7 * Box8;
  // casteamos el resultado a entero para eliminar los decimales y le agregamos nada para pasarlo a string!
  result = parseInt(result) +"";
  // ahora eliminamos el ultimo digito
  result = result.substr(0, result.length-1);

  //result.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("total").value = result;

  format(document.getElementById("total"));
}

var formatNumber = {
 separador: ".", // separador para los miles
 sepDecimal: ',', // separador para los decimales
 formatear:function (num){
  num +='';
  var splitStr = num.split('.');
  var splitLeft = splitStr[0];
  var splitRight = splitStr.length > 1 ? this.sepDecimal + splitStr[1] : '';
  var regx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
  while (regx.test(splitLeft)) {
  splitLeft = splitLeft.replace(regx, '$1' + this.separador + '$2');
  }
  return  splitLeft  +splitRight + ' ' + this.simbol;
 },
 new:function(num, simbol){
  this.simbol = simbol ||'';
  return this.formatear(num);
 }
}
function format(input) {
  var num = input.value;  
  input.value = formatNumber.new(num, "€");
} 
</script>
<input type="hidden" id="cuarenta" value="40" onkeyup="calculo()" /><br />   
<input type="hidden" id="cero" value="0.108253" onkeyup="calculo()" /><br />
<input type="hidden" id="sesenta" value="60" onkeyup="calculo()" /><br />
<input type="hidden" id="doce" value="12" onkeyup="calculo()" /><br />
<input type="hidden" id="doce" value="12" onkeyup="calculo()" /><br />
<input type="hidden" id="mil" value="1000" onkeyup="calculo()" /><br />
<input type="hidden" id="novecientoscincuenta" value="950" onkeyup="calculo()" />

<input type="text" name="Factura" id="factura" value="" onkeyup="calculo()"><br /><br />
<select class="form-control" onchange="calculo();" id="horario" name="Horario">
    <option selected>Seleccionar horario de consumo</option>
 <option id="dia" name="Día" value="60" onkeyup="calculo();" required>Día</option>
 <option id="noche" name="Noche" value="20" onkeyup="calculo();" required>Noche</option>
 <option id="ambos" name="Ambos" value="45" onkeyup="calculo();" required>Ambos</option>
</select><br /><br />

<input type="text" name="Total" id="total" value="" onkeyup="format(this)" disabled>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo!!!, me has enseñado con el 'parseInt' aunque el arreglo no está del todo preciso, no muestra los decimales con la coma como en el ejemplo, se puede solucionar??

Comment: en realidad es erroreneo pero si es lo que deseas `result = parseInt(result*(10**1)) +"";`

Comment: Perfecto!!! Muchas gracias!!!